# What is more pythonic - subclassing dict or creating external functions to manipulate them?

Tags: python, coding-style

Say I have a dictionary that contains complex classes that need to be loaded and unloaded in a special way. (Not especially special, just outside the bounds of this question.) Should I gracefully subclass the built-in dict like this:

```
class ExampleClass(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'ExampleClass; '+dict.__str__(self)

    @classmethod
    def loads(cls, string):
        <load object from string here>

    def dumps(self):
        <dump object here>
```

Or do something like this:

```
def load_special_structure(string):
    <load object from code here>

def dump_special_structure(obj):
    <dump object here>
```

That's all the extra functionality I need. It's not too pythonic to have to use a special imported method to dump and load it, but subclassing a dictionary isn't either. On the usage perspective, being able to import that class, load it from a string and use it like a dictionary is really useful.

Comment: What are the expected return types of the functions/methods? Always `dict` or always `ExampleClass`?

Answer (score 5):

In general, in Python I favor using functions over subclassing internal classes. In the end, if you write your `String -> dict` method, you end up working with a `dict`, pure as the driven snow. Just put your functions in a sensible module and import them only where needed; this will also encourage you *not* to import the functions everywhere, which will help you out by keeping the IO separated from your logic.

Comment: Sounds interesting. The thing is, the entire module actively deals with loading and unloading objects (i.e. all classes are functional, but they all implement a method of loading and unloading) and it's better if I can tell that its type is of that special kind. Something else less important is the fact that what it contains is custom objects containing custom objects, but in the end, it's just an arbitrary dictionary that, after many loads() and dumps() methods, requires importing a module just to load and dump it, which kind of defeats the purpose of Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Why would you load and dump many times? That seems like something that should happen only at the boundaries of your system. Also, if you need to carry information about the *kind* of object you have, I'd say you do need a class -- but I don't think it should be a subclass of `dict`.

Comment: Not many times, but I have to dump and load it for each server instance, and I don't wanna do `from utils.dataprocessing import load_blablabla, dump_blablabla`